# Radial limit of a Poisson integral of a measure

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $μ$ be a positive Borel measure on the unit circle and $dμ=dσ+fdm$ be its Lebesgue decompsition(m is the Lebesgue measure on the unit circle and $σ\perp m$).How can we show that the Poisson integral of $μ$, $P[dμ](z)$ has a radial limit $\infty$  $σ$ 
 almost everywhere? i.e. $$\lim_{r\to1^-}P[dμ](re^{iθ})=\infty \  σ \  almost \ everywhere $$

I can show that $P[dσ]=\infty \ σ \ a.e.$ but i am having trouble finding something for $P[fdm]=P[f]$ that is true $σ \ a.e.$(i know that $P[f] $ has a radial limit $f(e^{iθ})$ $m\ a.e.$)

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the positivity of $\mu$ Imply $f\ge 0?$

Comment: @zhw Yes!Thats right and it is enough for what i want to prove(my bad i didnt notice this...).But is there anything i can say for $f$ thats true σ a.e.?

Comment: $P[f]\ge 0$ and since you know $P[d\sigma]$ has radial limit $\infty$ $\sigma$ a.e., the same is true when you add $P[f]$ to it.